# Como dividir o carrinho em 2 ou mais pacotes?

Tags: php, woocommerce, web-service

Como meu e-commerce só irá trabalhar com os correios, estou precisando que o carrinho seja dividido em mais de 1 pacote, hoje eu utilizo o plugin dos Correios criado pelo Cláudio (excelente plugin), onde o mesmo chegando a uma quantidade x de produtos no carrinho ele já não permite mais o envio, pois ele trata aquele carrinho somente como 1 pacote e excede o limite permitido pelos correios em peso cubico.

Não sei como exatamente seja a lógica utilizada no plugin para solicitar o valor de um frete junto aos correios. Eu imagino que seja informado aos correios as informações como dimensões e peso dos produtos e o sistema dos correios automaticamente faz o cálculo e retorna o valor do frete.

Não tenho muita experiência com PHP e nem com Woocommerce, mas gostaria de saber se seria possível ser efetuada a lógica abaixo:

- Cliente envia um produto para o carrinho;
- O produto, com suas dimensões e peso preenchidos, seria efetuado o cálculo de peso cúbico conforme a fórmula dos correios;
- Com o peso cúbico calculado, o mesmo seria utilizado para ir "acumulando" em uma variável (pacote), até um valor X limitante, valor esse seria o peso cúbico máximo permitido pelos correios;
- Quando a primeira variável (pacote1) fosse completada, seria criada uma nova variável (pacote2) e seria preenchida com os outros produtos que forem sendo inseridos no carrinho e assim por diante;
- Quando solicitado o valor do frete, seria feita uma quantidade de requisição de frete junto aos correios conforme a quantidade de pacotes criados;
- Com os valores dos fretes retornado, efetuar a soma dos mesmos e mostrar ao cliente somente o valor total da soma das requisições, de acordo claro com o tipo de envio (PAC, SEDEX, SEDEX10 etc..).

Sei que é uma ideia meio doida, mas creio que muitas pessoas hoje tem o mesmo problema que eu em relação a enviar muitas mercadorias via Correios.

O único problema que vejo nisso é em relação ao número de rastreamento que seria gerado, uma vez que seria em mais de 1 pacote, iria ser criado mais de 1 código de rastreamento, oque complicaria a automatização hoje feita para informar os clientes via e-mail.

Obs.: Hoje decidi utilizar somente os correios para efetuar as entregas dos meus produtos pois analisando e simulando junto a algumas transportadoras mais utilizadas no mercado, verifiquei que seria mais caro eu enviar por uma transportadora um pacote maior do que 2 pacotes menores pelos Correios (pelo menos no meu caso é possível dividir em vários pacotes), fora que os Correios fazem praticamente o Brasil inteiro e as transportadoras não.

Comment: primeiro acho que não é uma ideia doida, acredito que muitos lojistas que postam via correios devem sofrer com isso. A lista que colou com as etapas, para mim esta corretissima, lembrando que tem limite de volume cubico e peso, entao o que acontecer primeiro ja deve contar como pacote unico. Quanto a parte dos codigos de rastreio, acho que vai ter mudar algo no painel do woocomerce para exibir os 2. Como não trabalho com woocommerce nao posso ajudar com o codigo :(

Comment: Certamente não há nada de doido aí... rsrs..  isso é o correto a se fazer. A implicação é referente aos códigos de rastreio. Nesse caso vc tem que verificar com o suporte técnico da transportadora (Correios), para verificar possibilidade de gerar um único código.